# Error: SELECT list expression references column created_utc which is neither grouped nor aggregated at [2:49]

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a table: t

My goal: To extract only the "id" with the highest score in the table and group it by the week_number.

Query:

```
SELECT id, 
       CAST(EXTRACT(WEEK FROM TIMESTAMP_SECONDS(created_utc)) AS STRING) AS week_number, 
       MAX(score) AS highest_score
FROM t 
WHERE body='r/twinpeaks'
GROUP BY id;
```

I am getting this error:
Error: SELECT list expression references column created_utc which is neither grouped nor aggregated at [2:49]

I tried doing this instead:

```
SELECT id, 
       CAST(EXTRACT(WEEK FROM TIMESTAMP_SECONDS(created_utc)) AS STRING) AS week_number, 
       MAX(score) AS highest_score
FROM  t 
WHERE body='r/twinpeaks'
GROUP BY week_number, id;
```

But this is what I got:

```
Row  id            week_number  highest_score    
1    dmkb6sv      36            1    
2    dn1cd2s      37            2    
3    dn43h1k      38            16   
4    dn3xf18      38            1    
5    dn7i1ko      38            1
6    dnpr9b1      39            1
```

I want this:

```
Row  id            week_number  highest_score    
1    dmkb6sv      36            1    
2    dn1cd2s      37            2    
3    dn43h1k      38            16   
6    dnpr9b1      39            1
```

Comment: provide simplified example of rows in your table along with expected result

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may try using `ROW_NUMBER` here:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT id,
        CAST(EXTRACT(WEEK FROM TIMESTAMP_SECONDS(created_utc)) AS STRING) AS week_number,
        score,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY
            CAST(EXTRACT(WEEK FROM TIMESTAMP_SECONDS(created_utc)) AS STRING)
            ORDER BY score DESC) rn
    FROM t 
    WHERE body = 'r/twinpeaks'
) t
WHERE rn = 1;
```

This would return the record with the highest score from each respective week number.  I am assuming here that you either do not care about ties for first, or that ties do not occur.  If you need to deal with ties, then a rank function could be used in place of row number.

Comment: This gives me an error: Error: Syntax error: Unexpected keyword ORDER at [9:13]

Comment: @AGuyHasNoName Missing closing parenthesis after `TIMESTAMP_SECONDS`.  Please retry my edited answer.

Comment: This output the desired result! Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT 
  EXTRACT(WEEK FROM TIMESTAMP_SECONDS(created_utc)) AS week_number,
  ARRAY_AGG(id ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 1)[OFFSET(0)] id,
  ARRAY_AGG(score ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 1)[OFFSET(0)] highest_score    
FROM `project.dataset.table` 
WHERE body = 'r/twinpeaks'
GROUP BY week_number
ORDER BY week_number
```